# vue with nginx: path not matching

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, vue.js, vuejs2

I am setting up vue(2.1.x) with nginx(1.10.2), I have following configuration:

```
location / {
    root   /var/lib/myRepo/dist/;
    index  index.html;
}
```

This works when I hit 'http://localhost:8080/', but when I hit other URLs like: 'http://localhost:8080/products/home', I get:

> 404 Not Found

I also tried following:

```
root   /var/lib/myRepo/dist/;
location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ index.html$query_string;
}
```

What can be wrong here and how to correct this.

Comment: How about `try_files $uri $uri/ index.html?$query_string`? (add a `?`)

Comment: @PanJunjie潘俊杰 Thanks for suggestion but no improvement, still same issue.

Comment: Try this `try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri $uri/ /index.html`

Comment: maybe removing the trailing slash to root ?

Answer (score 1):

you can follow like this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @router;
        index index.html;
    }

    location @router {
        rewrite ^.*$ /index.html last;
    }
}
```